# Fail to post submittion of form-data

Tags: scala, http, playframework

Im trying to perform a POST call in Play that submit a form data with email and password text.

This is what I've tried so far but this does not compiles:

```
def ws: WSClient

ws.url(railsLoginApi).withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json").post(Form("email" -> "xxx", "pass" -> "xxx"))
```

But I get an error in `Form("email" -> "xxx", "pass" -> "xxx")` saying:

> unspecified value parameters. erro: seq[FormError] value:
>   Option[NotInferedT]

Does someone knows how to perform this in play using Scala?

Comment: See this: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Submitting-form-data

Answer (score 0):

*As the url is accepting the form data. Content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and body format will be like `MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo`*

```
ws.url(railsLoginApi)
.withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.post[String](Map("email" -> "xxx", "pass" -> "xxx").map { case (k, v) => s"$k=$v"}.mkString("&"))
```